# Similar matrices and linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

[image: I have no idea about this, can someone give me some hints? Thanks!]
I think they may represent the same thing but don't know how to prove it. The only thing I can think of is to write the definitions of A & B in the def'n 1. Then what's next?

Comment: How do you change the basis of a linear transformation?  Take a vector in the new basis, express it in the old basis, apply the transformation, and then express the result in the new basis.  Sort of like changing variables when doing indefinite integration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

$P$ is the matrix that represents the change of basis.